# Uniqueness of idempotent completion

Tags: category-theory

Is a [idempotent completion](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Karoubi+envelope) of a given category unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unique up to unique equivalence, as with all things specified by a universal property. Recall:

> An **idempotent-completion** of a category $\mathcal{C}$ is a functor $\mathcal{C} \to \hat{\mathcal{C}}$ where $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ is idempotent-complete and, for every idempotent-complete category $\mathcal{D}$, the restriction functor
>   $$[\hat{\mathcal{C}}, \mathcal{D}] \to [\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}]$$
>   is fully faithful and essentially surjective on objects.